# Get the host name from different subnets

Tags: c#

I can get the host name of any PC on the local network fine using the browser, i.e my c# code gets the IP address then uses DNS to resolve the host name etc., but it does not work for other subnets.

is it possible to get the host name of the PC in different local subnets?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your current code so we can help you from there. You might find helpful reading how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Your PC has only one host name that it knows of itself. As for DNS aliases, of which there could be many, you'd have to ask the DNS servers that serve those subnets. Theoretically, I could make an alias for one of your PC's IP addresses and call it `hippo`, but there's not really any way for you to find that. If you really want the *local* host name, you can use PowerShell remoting or WMI to query the computer remotely for what it thinks its hostname is.

Comment: normally if you question an authorative DNS server and set q=any it will return aliases